# How to lengthen the allowed text in the scroll effect?

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is a page from my website. http://teleportcorp.com/management.html Notice how the text gets cut off and the scrolling animation resets. Can someone help me identify the css parameter that would allow me to add alrger chunks of text like this one without it getting cut off?

`Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by the classical author and philosopher Cicero. Its words and letters have been changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Latin, it actually has no meaning whatsoever. As Cicero's text doesn't contain the letters K, W, or Z, alien to latin, these, and others are often inserted randomly to mimic the typographic appearence of European languages, as are digraphs not to be found in the original.`

I'm not sure what the css Parameter is to do this.

Here is the code. You can copy and paste the above chunk between the `<p class="marquee"></p>` Tags. Thank you.

https://codepen.io/jonathansampson/pen/rqemL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called marquee.

they used css `@keyframes` to simulate this effect.

```
.marquee {
top: 6em;
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;
animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes marquee
0% {
top: 8em;
}

100% {
top: -11em;
}
```

for better understanding it's better to use below code on your `@keyframes`:

```
@keyframes marquee {
0%   { transform: translatey(100%);}
100% { transform: translatey(-100%);}
}
```

check some examples here:
[Css Marquee](https://www.quackit.com/css/codes/marquees/)

Comment: so which number should I change? I feel i've already tried playing around with them but I cant come up with a configuration that will fit my text

Comment: @user3233623 change this part : 100% { top: -8em } it change by your text.

Comment: is the current code botched? When I change `15s` to `25s` it just scrolls slower but still resets after cutting off half the text. When I change `-11em` to `-25em` it just scrolls faster which makes it harder for readers.

Comment: change it to what? I think it just makes the text scroll faster. I need to to be slow and long. It resets after 15 seconds and when I increase that time, it just makes the text scroll slower while still getting cut off half way through. Even if I change it to 100 seconds...

Comment: I'll try to tweak it and see if I get lucky. Thank you all.

Comment: time attribute on animation property just set your animation time. if it set to 15 you top property will gradually change from -11em to -25em in 15 seconds. you can make animation faster or slower with it.